# How to randomly get an attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I know how to get the `type` attribute of the first `input` element:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var type = document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].type;
  document.getElementById("p").textContent = type;
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
<input type="url">
<button id="button">Get it</button>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Is there a way to randomly get a `type` attribute, no matter which, so I don't have to specify the `input` index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()` to get a random index in the range of `length` of inputs

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')];
  let type = inputs[Math.floor(Math.random() * inputs.length)].type
  document.getElementById("p").textContent = type;
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
<input type="url">
<button id="button">Get it</button>
<p id="p"></p>
```